# Can I encrypt my disk after installing?

Tags: 12.04, encryption

I did not chose to encrypt the full disk when I installed Ubuntu. Can I do it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for encrypting file system in Linux you can use a tool called [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/).

more information for about how to use this tool can be found **[here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-encrypt-directories-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian-squeeze)** and the tool official documentation.read them carefully.

Comment: This answer could use a little improvement. While the link may contain valuable information it might be better to post at least an overview here. I also want to mention that this link is intended for debian.